# Is there a way to replace the default image-not-loaded-yet browser icon?

Tags: javascript, image, browser, photos

(Note this does not refer broken images as therefore not a duplicate of previously asked questions).

I'd like to find or build a IMG wrapper that first shows a default background image from the local cache before showing the intended photo once it has loaded, similar to what Pinterest does (although  Pinterest is even cooler and detects a color background that complements the image that's loading).

I have an app which loads a lot of photos - hundreds - and I would like to make the way they load in a feature rather than an ugly artifact of the browser.

Wouldn't it be cool if they looked liked this?

http://screencast.com/t/qlTUN9Z3MO

rather than like this

http://screencast.com/t/qlTUN9Z3MO

Can that be done?

Comment: @zerkms, I interpreted it as in-progress, rather than `404`.  Simon, which did you mean?

Comment: I have no idea how this could be closed as a duplicate. Looks like we got some trigger-happy folks here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a SVG `background-image` in your CSS.  You can also scale it to fit your display proportions using `background-size` [<sup>doc</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).  Also, remember to set your `img`'s size (with CSS or HTML attributes), rather than letting it use the size of the image.

First, you need a background svg.  You can use the simple `background-image: url(x.svg)` syntax, or consider using a data-url.  There's a [free tool](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php) for encoding them.

Next, you'll want to set the size of your background.  If your image viewer has a distinct aspect ratio, make your svg the same proportions.  Then, tell it to fill either vertically or horizontally.  It shouldn't matter, but in the case of a fluke, I find vertical more reliable.

```
background-size: auto 100%; /* Vertical (full height) */
background-size: 100%; /* Horizontal (full width) */
```

Now while your image is loading, the `background-image` will show instead.  Once it's loaded; it'll cover the background (assuming fully opaque).

Comment: I also found this [http://blog.embed.ly/post/51071740487/pinterest-colored-background-placeholders?source=sendgrid] which is very cool.